# How to debug why my program does not solve the stated problem?

Tags: c

This is my university assignment:

> Material X replicates itself, producing one identical X every 10 minutes. For instance, if there is one X initially, it becomes two after 10 minutes. In other words, until 9 minutes, there is only one X, occupying a total volume of 1. At 10 minutes, the volume occupied by X becomes 2.
>
> You need to transport material X from Laboratory A to Factory B. However, there is a volume limitation on the truck, so you must ensure that the capacity of the truck is not exceeded while transporting X. You are provided with the capacity of the truck and the time it takes to travel from Laboratory A to Factory B. Ignoring the time it takes to load and unload X and assuming no change in volume due to physical forces, how many units of material X can be loaded onto the truck at Laboratory A? Loading capacity should not exceed the capacity of the truck until it arrives at Factory B. (Consider the volume of one unit of material X to be 1.)
>
> Input Format:
>
> Two integers, c and t, indicating the capacity of the truck and the time it takes to travel from Laboratory A to Factory B, are provided as input.
>
> ( 0 < c, t < 1001)
>
> Output Format:
>
> The output format should follow the same format as the Sample Output below. Print the maximum number of units of material X that can be loaded onto the truck. Ensure that there is a blank line between each case. If it is not possible to load the material, print "Can not".

I tried to solve this problem about 4~5 hrs, what's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int capacity, time;
    scanf("%d%d", &capacity, &time);
  
    int VofX = (time / 10) + 1;
    
    int numX = capacity / VofX;

    if(numX <= 0){
        printf("Can not\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("%d\n", numX);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is t measured in? seconds? minutes? hours?... If minutes, isn't it just floor(c/powf(2,t/10.0f))?

Comment: What is the current output of the program as it stands?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the math first.

- 1
- after 10 minutes 2
- after 20 minutes 4
- after 30 minutes 8
- etc etc

As you see they are powers of `2`

So you need to use power of two to calculate the number of material 'X' after `n` periods Your formula is.

```
int VofX = 1 << (time / 10);
```

because in binary arithmetic `2^n == 1 << (n - 1)` for `n >= 1`, where `^` is power (it is not C as `^` means binary XOR in C language)

But you are limited to integers (the capacity too):

```
int main(){
    int capacity, time, numX;
    scanf("%d%d", &capacity, &time);
  
    int VofX = (time / 10);
    
    if(VofX > (sizeof(capacity) * CHAR_BIT - 1))
    {
        numX = -1;
    } 
    else
    {
        numX = 1 << VofX;
    }


    if(numX <= 0 || capacity < numX){
        printf("Can not\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("%d\n", numX);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work because `time` may be up to 1001, so `1 << (time / 10)` will overflow in all current ordinary C implementations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil then it is not doable using integers as per provided template.

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil capacity is limited to integer too

Comment: `VofX > (sizeof(capacity) * CHAR_BIT - 1)` allows `VofX` to be 31 (with 32-bit integers), and then `1 << VofX` overflows.

Comment: For input of `1` and `10`, this code reports “Can not”. However, the wording of the problem statement suggests that this is allowed, as the capacity is not exceeded until the moment the truck arrives at the factory, although wording is not entirely clear (“Loading capacity should not exceed the capacity of the truck until it arrives at Factory B”). At least, the issue ought to be pointed out so the OP can consider it and test both options (if there is an automatic grader) or ask the instructor for clarification.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if it is 10 then the period has passed  and number is 2

Comment: The problem statement is not only unclear but is actually contradictory on this. It says both “it becomes two **after** 10 minutes” and “**At** 10 minutes, the volume occupied by X becomes 2.” These are different statements, and the proper procedure is not to assume whichever one you like is correct but to question the problem statement and get it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement appears to specify that material X doubles in volume each 10 minutes. This means the volume forms a geometric series: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16,…

Dividing the capacity by the number of doublings will not tell you how much initial material can be carried. Division is for a linear relationship, such as *volume* = *constant* • *time*. This is an exponential relationship, *volume* = *constant*<sub>0</sub> • 2<sup>*constant*<sub>1</sub>•*time*</sup>.

For this particular problem, calculating the initial volume that can be carried is fairly simple: Divide the capacity by two for each ten minutes the material will be on the truck.

There is some question about the border case; the wording seems to suggest that, if the material exceeds the truck capacity at the exact moment the truck arrives at the factory, that is okay. This affects whether to use `10 < t` or `10 <= t` in the code below.

Assuming `t` is in units of minutes, one solution (for a single case) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    int c, t;
    if (2 != scanf("%d%d", &c, &t))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, invalid input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //  Divide the capacity by two every ten minutes.
    for (; 10 < t; t -= 10)
        c /= 2;

    if (0 < c)
        printf("%d\n", c);
    else
        printf("Can not\n");
}
```

(It is left to the reader to modify the code to handle multiple cases as the problem statement suggests.)

Note this presumes that material X is only available in whole units. If fractional units are possible, then some amount of material X can always be loaded onto the truck, and the program needs to be modified to handle fractions. The problem statement seems to only address integer quantities.

Comment: I do not see any loops in the template. Are they allowed? I think only arithmetic solution is allowed

Comment: @gulpr: No such constraints are stated in the problem statement. The post does not say the code shown is a template.

Answer (score -1):

I would go for:

```
int t = 33;   // Time
int c = 962;  // Capacity
int initial = 0;

t = t / 10; // Number of times X will be doubled
if ((size_t)t < sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT) {
    initial = c >> t; // Divide capacity with 2^t (here ^ is "to the power of")
}

printf("Max initial X is %d\n", initial);
```

Output:

```
Max initial X is 120
```

The idea is to calculate "backswards", i.e. start with the maximum capacity and then divide by 2 the number of times that a double will occur, i.e. travel time divided by 10

Comment: @EricPostpischil Correct. I forgot the "If the value of the right operand ..... is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined" part of the standard